# MVC update database table method query

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The snippet of code below updates an employee record.
This seems to be the correct way of doing things but it seems odd that you need to query the database before the update to get the current values of the record.
In the old days of .net you just used to run the update statement and all would be fine.
Is there a way in MVC of updating the record woithout having to select the unaltered record first?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(staff2.Models.editEmployeeViewModel evm)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            staff.Models.Employee emp = context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmpId == id);

            emp.EmpSurname = evm.lastname;
            emp.EmpFirstname = evm.firstName;
            emp.EmpExt = evm.EmpExt;

            context.updateEmployee(emp);
            context.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("/Details/" + employee.empID, null, null);

        }

        return View(employee);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a web environment you are working in a disconnected and stateless environment. You therefore need to tell the database what needs to be updated. All you need a reference to the entity and EF will take care of the rest. It may seem strange but after a while it becomes second nature.